# c++ how to expess a mathematical term

Tags: c++

i have the following :
[image]

I only want (for now) to express the (s 1) , (s 2) term .
For example ,(s 1)=s  , (s 2)= s(s-1)/2! , (s 3)=s(s-1)(s-2)/3!.

I created a factorial function :

```
//compute factorial
int fact(int x){

if (x==0)
return 1;
else
    return fact(x-1)*x;

}
```

and i have problem in how to do right the above.

```
.....
double s=(z-x[1])/h;
double s_term=0;
    for (int p=1;p<=n;p++){
        if p==1 
            s_term=s;
            else
                    s_term=s*(s-p)/fact(p+1);

    }
```

Also, it is that : s=(x - x0)/h.
I don't know if i have declared right the s above.(i use x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVCEc.png) in the declaration because this is my starting point)

Thank you!

Comment: Tip #1 - don't implement factorial recursively.

Comment: `double BinomialCoeff(const int n, const int k) { return double(fact(n)) / ( fact(k) * fact(n-k) ); }`

Comment: Tip #2 - don't use factorials to calculate binomial coefficients. Not only is it inefficient, it's a good way to get unnecessary overflows. Consider `\binom{1000}{2}` - that's just `1000*999/2*1`, which is easy, while `1000!/(2!*998!)` is unlikely to work out.

Comment: @Jefromi: added double casting, so its up to his `fact(n)` function which uses int (`unsigned long long` would be better of course)

Comment: @sled: Moot point. There's no reason to use factorials; you'll do more  calculation *and* have larger intermediate values than necessary. Sure, bigger ints will let you go farther, but `n! ~ O(n^n)`. Just don't do it.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the tips,i just wanted to do it with factorials right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factorial part will be much more efficient using a loop rather than recursion.

As for the binomial coefficients, the line:

```
s_term=s*(s-p)/fact(p+1);
```

isn't going to have the desired effect, as you're only setting the first and last terms correctly and missing out the (s-1), (s-2), ..., (s-p+1) terms. It's easier to just use:

```
s_term = fact(s) / (fact(p) * fact(s-p))
```

for s choose p.

Comment: :When you are saying 'for s choose p' you mean instead of doing double s=(z-x[1])/h ?

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the Binomial Coefficient simply using this function (probably the best for performance and memory usage):

```
unsigned long long ComputeBinomialCoefficient( int n, int k )
{
        // Run-time assert to ensure correct behavior
        assert( n > k && n > 1 );

        // Exploit the symmetry in the line x = k/2:
        if( k > n - k )
                k = n - k;

        unsigned long long c(1);
        // Perform the product over the space i = [1...k]
        for( int i = 1; i < k+1; i++ )
        {
                c *= n - (k - i);
                c /= i;
        }

        return c;

}
```

You can then just call this when you see the brackets. (<strike>I'm assuming that is the Binomial Coefficient, rather than a 2D column vector?</strike>). This technique only uses 2 variables internally (taking up a grand total of 12 bytes), and uses no recursion.

Hope this helps! :)

EDIT: I'm curious how you're going to do the (I assume laplacian) operator? Are you intending to do the forward difference method for discrete values of x, and then calculate the 2nd derivative using the results from the first, then take the quotient?

Comment: :Hello,thanks a lot for the help.I will have this in mind for the future.I just wanted to do it with factorial to understand how can i implement the code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out implementing factorial and binomial coefficient functions is not easy (e.g. overflows lurk everywhere).

If you are interested in reasonable implementations as opposed to implementing all this yourself have a look at what is available in [gsl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) which everybody dealing with numerical problems should know of.

```
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_gamma.h>

double factorial_10  = gsl_sf_fact(10);
double ten_over_four = gsl_sf_choose(10, 4);
```

Have also a look at the documentation. There are numerous functions returning the log instead of the value [to avoid overflow problems](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/07/math-library-functions-that-seem-unnecessary/).